# append the loop results to a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to get the list of variable names where the count of value "a" is more than or equals 2 and finally store it in a vector Morethan2 and similarly do for the lessthan2.  Please help me to achieve this.

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = c("a","a","b"),a2 = c("a","b","b"),a3 = c("a","a","a"))
for(x in names(df[1:3])){
  if(sum(df[x] =="a") >= 2){
    more2 = x
    } else{less2 = x}}
Lessthan2 = less2
Morethan2 = more2
```

Expected REsult:

```
Morethan2  : 'a1','a3'
Lessthan2  : 'a2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colSums` to get the count of `"a"` in each column and then subset it to get `morethan2` and `lessthan2`.

```
inds <- colSums(df == "a")
morethan2 <- names(inds)[inds >= 2]
lessthan2 <- names(inds)[inds < 2]

morethan2
#[1] "a1" "a3"
lessthan2
#[1] "a2"
```

---

If we want to use `for` loop, we can do

```
i <- 1
j  <- 1
more2 <- numeric()
less2 <- numeric()

for(x in names(df)) {
   if(sum(df[[x]] =="a") >= 2) {
      more2[i] = x
     i= i + 1
   } else {
     less2[j] = x
     j = j + 1
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, could you also please post the same using the for loop?

Comment: @prog Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = c("a","a","b"),a2 = c("a","b","b"),a3 = c("a","a","a"))
more2 <- c()
less2 <- c()
for(x in names(df[1:3])){
  if(sum(df[x] =="a") >= 2){
    more2[x] = x
  } else{less2 [x] = x}}
```